# How to make an UIPickerView with a Done button?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am having difficulties to make an UIPickerView with a done button to appear when the users taps a UITextField. This is my code so far. Everything builds fine, but when I tap the text field, the keyboard appears, not the picker.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField!

let pickerData = ["11", "12", "13"]





@IBAction func textButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let picker: UIPickerView
    picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 300))
    picker.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()

    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")

    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    textField1.inputView = picker
    textField1.inputAccessoryView = toolBar




}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    textField1.text = pickerData[row]
}

func donePicker() {

    textField1.resignFirstResponder()

}




}
```

Comment: where are you calling textButton method?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Add this code to your `viewDidLoad()` instead of method

```
let picker: UIPickerView
picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 300))
picker.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()

picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
picker.delegate = self
picker.dataSource = self

let toolBar = UIToolbar()
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
toolBar.isTranslucent = true
toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
toolBar.sizeToFit()

let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: self, action: #selector(self. donePicker))
let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self. donePicker))

toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

textField1.inputView = picker
textField1.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

Comment: Its probably for a different thread. But when I hit done using above example, the uipickerview item is not selected. How do I do that?

Comment: @iAnurag I want to display picker on tap of button and selecting after selecting from Picker assign it to button title. So inputAccessoryView won't work for UIButton. Any other solution?

Comment: is it possible to align the buttons on the right side of the toolbar?

Comment: found the solution, add the following as first item: let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

Comment: That would be great if you can update your answer for swift 4 or 5

Comment: the done button doesn't call the method, it only closes the pickerview ios 12 swift 4.2

Answer (score 60):

I think it's better to make a custom class to remove code from controller.

**Swift 4/5 example**:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol ToolbarPickerViewDelegate: class {
    func didTapDone()
    func didTapCancel()
}

class ToolbarPickerView: UIPickerView {

    public private(set) var toolbar: UIToolbar?
    public weak var toolbarDelegate: ToolbarPickerViewDelegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = .black
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneTapped))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelTapped))

        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        self.toolbar = toolBar
    }

    @objc func doneTapped() {
        self.toolbarDelegate?.didTapDone()
    }

    @objc func cancelTapped() {
        self.toolbarDelegate?.didTapCancel()
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    fileprivate let pickerView = ToolbarPickerView()
    fileprivate let titles = ["0", "1", "2", "3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.textField.inputView = self.pickerView
        self.textField.inputAccessoryView = self.pickerView.toolbar

        self.pickerView.dataSource = self
        self.pickerView.delegate = self
        self.pickerView.toolbarDelegate = self

        self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    }
}

extension MyViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.titles.count
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return self.titles[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        self.textField.text = self.titles[row]
    }
}

extension MyViewController: ToolbarPickerViewDelegate {

    func didTapDone() {
        let row = self.pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        self.pickerView.selectRow(row, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
        self.textView.text = self.titles[row]
        self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func didTapCancel() {
        self.textField.text = nil
        self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: It might better for `didTapDone` and `didTapCancel` method to pass in the `ToolbarPickerView` instance; like `func didTapDone(_ picker: ToolbarPickerView)`

Answer (score 28):

**UIPickerView with a Done button? Swift4**

Step 1 : Adding one textFiled named  txt_pickUpData in ViewController and give IBOutlet connection and delegate. also take one UIDatePicker variable. and take an Array with string value which is display on picker wheel.

```
@IBOutlet weak var txt_pickUpData: UITextField!
var myPickerView : UIPickerView!
var pickerData = ["Hitesh Modi" , "Kirit Modi" , "Ganesh Modi" , "Paresh Modi"]
```

Step 2 :  Also adding the delegate of UIPickerView and UITextFiled.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate{
```

Step 3 : The function pickUp to create UIPickerView with ToolBar.

```
func pickUp(_ textField : UITextField){

// UIPickerView
self.myPickerView = UIPickerView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 216))
self.myPickerView.delegate = self
self.myPickerView.dataSource = self
self.myPickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
textField.inputView = self.myPickerView

// ToolBar
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
toolBar.barStyle = .default
toolBar.isTranslucent = true
toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 216/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
toolBar.sizeToFit()

// Adding Button ToolBar
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.doneClick))
let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.cancelClick))
toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

 }
```

Step 4 : Adding the delegate and datasource methods of UIPickerView to display data on UIPickerView wheel.

```
//MARK:- PickerView Delegate & DataSource
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
return 1
 }
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
return pickerData.count
 }
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
return pickerData[row]
  }
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
self.txt_pickUpData.text = pickerData[row]
 }
 //MARK:- TextFiled Delegate

 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
self.pickUp(txt_pickUpData)
 }
```

Step 5 : Adding two buttons method which which is in ToolBar. One is doneClick and other is cancelClick. Which is dismiss the UIPickerView.

```
@objc func doneClick() {
  txt_pickUpData.resignFirstResponder()
 }
@objc func cancelClick() {
  txt_pickUpData.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Step 6 : Calling the pickUp function in UITextField delegate method.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
self.pickUp(txt_pickUpData)
}
```

Just copy and paste in Your code.

Comment: Note that in Swift 4 you will need to add `@objc` in front of your `doneClick` and `cancelClick` functions.

Comment: Thank you for so full answer! I also note that we should remember to set our ViewController as a textField delegate - txt_pickUpData.delegate = self. I did it the the storyboard

Comment: You can also add `#selector()` for the actions

Answer (score 8):

People seem to be using the code here to other questions to ask the same thing that [VBaarathi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3085198/vbaarathi)  asked

In Swift3

```
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(donePicker))
let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(donePicker))
```

Then you can put the following in the same swift file

```
func donePicker (sender:UIBarButtonItem)
{
     // Put something here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3x:**

The awesome answer is already given but here is the different approach, just make a `pickerView` and give the `inputView` and `inputAccessoryView` like this:

```
YOUR_TEXTFIELD_NAME.inputView = picker


func addKeyboardToolBar() {

  var nextButton: UIBarButtonItem?
  var keyboardToolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: 
  CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(pickerView.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(25)))
  keyboardToolBar.sizeToFit()
  keyboardToolBar.barStyle = .default
  daysHourTextField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar
  nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.textFieldShouldReturn))
  keyboardToolBar.items = [UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil), nextButton]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the IQKeyboardManager library. After setting it up, it will automatically add the Done button for you.  Check it out here: [github](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

First install the pod with

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```

Then In AppDelegate.swift, just import IQKeyboardManagerSwift framework and enable IQKeyboardManager.

```
 import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

 @UIApplicationMain
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

   var window: UIWindow?

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
    [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

    return true
  }
}
```

This library will automatically add the Done button in the Keyboard for you.