# Show a UIPickerView when a button is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uipickerview

[image]

I want to open a UIPickerView on the click of this button. 
I had created this button and now when the user clicks on it I want to open a UIPickerView. I have seen many tutorials on the Internet but all of them are showing with:

```
textfield.inputview = uipker // i don't want to use extfield
```

But want to implement it without a textfield.
Is it possible and if possible then tell me how can I do that.

Comment: you can create pickerview and add it as subview to main view, if you want it on button click. But most preferred way is to use textfield instead of button.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to do it from Interface Builder then you can add `UIPickerView` in your storyBoard and initially hide that `UIPickerView` and when your button tapped show it.

If you want to do this by coding then you can try this.

Define this as global.

```
var toolBar = UIToolbar()
var picker  = UIPickerView()
```

Add below code inside your button tap action. I have added `Done` button in toolbar to dismiss picker.

**Note :** I write entire code in button action if you don't want to do that just write all code in `viewDidLoad` and write only these line in your button action `self.view.addSubview(picker)` and `self.view.addSubview(toolBar)`

```
@IBAction func YOUR_BUTTON__TAP_ACTION(_ sender: UIButton) {
    picker = UIPickerView.init()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self
    picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    picker.setValue(UIColor.black, forKey: "textColor")
    picker.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
    picker.contentMode = .center
    picker.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 300, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 300)
    self.view.addSubview(picker)
            
    toolBar = UIToolbar.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 300, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 50))
    toolBar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent
    toolBar.items = [UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(onDoneButtonTapped))]
    self.view.addSubview(toolBar)
}
```

On Done button you can remove toolBar as well as PickerView.

```
@objc func onDoneButtonTapped() {
    toolBar.removeFromSuperview()
    picker.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Delegate methods of `UIPickerView`

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
    
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return YOUR_DATA_ARRAY.COUNT
}
    
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return YOUR_DATA_ARRAY[row]
}
    
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print(YOUR_DATA_ARRAY[row])
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kuldeep .. I am just adding the ```UIPickerViewDataSource``` and ```picker.dataSource = self ``` to your response.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide/show your `uipickerview`. Add the picker as subview of main view in storyboard but keep it hidden. On clicking on that button show it.

Add toolbar with done button to hide the picker again. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728680/how-to-make-an-uipickerview-with-a-done-button) a link for that

Comment: won't this be memory intensive ?